# Windows 7 mysql2 gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mysql2

I am running rails on Windows 7.
So I originally got an error that said:

```
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb

checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
***extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers
```

I then went through stackoverflow and saw that to fix this I need to just do gem install mysql2. I did that but get this error now:

```
gem install mysql2

ERROR: while executing gem... (NameError)
uinitialized constant Psyck::Syck
```

Comment: Try installing an older version of the mysql2 gem.

Answer (score 2):

Using `gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.9` could do the trick.